# How to handle many connections to a large MySQL database

Tags: mysql, java, hibernate

I have multiple java hibernate apps connecting to 1 single mysql DB. Sometimes some of the apps hangs on DB select query. I think it is because of many connections the apps are to DB and remains open. So, I changed variables 'wait_timeout=3' & 'interactive_timeout=3600' & 'max_connections=5000'. After that, I saw many errors/exceptions of not being able to connect to DB OR not being able to insert into DB. Therefore I reset all 3 above variables to their default values: 'wait_timeout=28800' & 'interactive_timeout=28800' & 'max_connections=151'. Now there is no error/exception but hangs of the apps. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

When the app hangs on a query, it is because of one of these things:

- You are using MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.
- Another query is blocking because it is locking something your "hung" query needs.  Find it.  Suggest `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` as a quick way that sometimes finds the problem.
- Your query is somehow slow.  Let's see the query that is "hanging", plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

`max_connections = 5000` is generally unwise -- it can lead to problems of its own.  `wait_timeout = 3` is masking the problem without solving it.

Comment: @Rick_James How to analyze the result of 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;', to see the locker query?

Comment: @MohsenAbasi - order them by time.  The ones that have been running the longest (other than a couple of system tasks) may be the villain.  Would you care to show us the `PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: @Rick_James I think that the issue is not from another query  lock. The connections count is high. Max_Connections is 151 and when I count threads of MySQL process (ps -T PIDofMySQL), it is 131. Do u agree with me that the connections limit is the issue?

Comment: @MohsenAbasi - `PROCESSLIST` is more useful than `ps`.

Comment: @Rick_James $ mysql --login-path=dbpass -e"show processlist" | wc -l
 resulted in: '75'
and '$ ps -T 31345 | wc -l' resulted in: '104'                                                         My max_connection var is '151'. However I can't run any new query!!!!

Comment: What does "can't run" mean?  "Can't connect" -- if so, what is the error message?  "Connected, but the query gets an error -- if so, what error?  Or, "takes a long time"?  I still want to see the output of `PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: takes an unusual long time...

Comment: Since MyISAM only does table locks, this could explain it.

Comment: Yes. My table's engine is MyISAM. So if I want to convert my table to InnoDB, Can I do it while inserting into the table? The table's data is very important and besides I can't now copy a backup of table since it contains many data and therefore it's backup takes many hours.

Comment: The conversion requires locking the table for the duration.  This will take hours to do all the tables.  You are "between a rock and a hard place".

Comment: What a good situation since I belongs to ALLAH and Islam. Any hard situation is easy for me